Is there a C# client for QuestDB to use with .NET Framework 4.8?
Is there a QuestDB client that's compatible with .NET Framework? I use .NET 4.8 and cannot go to .NET Core since I use ninjatrader. When I install net-questdb-client from nuget I get
... You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework, Version=v4.8', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework...
Is there a compatible version?
